Error fetching a specific repository when building a bazel project
Im trying to build the following project from source: https://github.com/google/xls
It utilizes bazel from as a build system and has a couple additional steps for building from source, which I've followed pretty closely. You can see them here: https://google.github.io/xls/
My setup is as follows:
Ubuntu 22.04.5 running on WSL 2.3.24.0
Bazel-7.4.0
Whenever I try to build it, it always fails within a couple of minutes with the following stacktrace:

    An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'org_theopenroadproject_asap7sc7p5t_27':
   Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/ivan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ivan/4b7fa2f66bee2e76a1c3cd0648b6021f/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl", line 136, column 45, in _http_archive_impl
                download_info = ctx.download_and_extract(
Error in download_and_extract: java.io.IOException: Error downloading [https://github.com/The-OpenROAD-Project/asap7sc7p5t_27/archive/900f55ed8bef025f39edcc8b8be5e04a2c55c15a.tar.gz] to /home/ivan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ivan/4b7fa2f66bee2e76a1c3cd0648b6021f/external/org_theopenroadproject_asap7sc7p5t_27/temp9565703453065543452/900f55ed8bef025f39edcc8b8be5e04a2c55c15a.tar.gz: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
ERROR: no such package '@@org_theopenroadproject_asap7sc7p5t_27//': java.io.IOException: Error downloading [https://github.com/The-OpenROAD-Project/asap7sc7p5t_27/archive/900f55ed8bef025f39edcc8b8be5e04a2c55c15a.tar.gz] to /home/ivan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ivan/4b7fa2f66bee2e76a1c3cd0648b6021f/external/org_theopenroadproject_asap7sc7p5t_27/temp9565703453065543452/900f55ed8bef025f39edcc8b8be5e04a2c55c15a.tar.gz: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
ERROR: /home/ivan/xls/xls/modules/rle/BUILD:183:15: //xls/modules/rle:rle_enc_synth_asap7 depends on @@org_theopenroadproject_asap7sc7p5t_27//:asap7-sc7p5t_rev27_rvt in repository @@org_theopenroadproject_asap7sc7p5t_27 which failed to fetch. no such package '@@org_theopenroadproject_asap7sc7p5t_27//': java.io.IOException: Error downloading [https://github.com/The-OpenROAD-Project/asap7sc7p5t_27/archive/900f55ed8bef025f39edcc8b8be5e04a2c55c15a.tar.gz] to /home/ivan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ivan/4b7fa2f66bee2e76a1c3cd0648b6021f/external/org_theopenroadproject_asap7sc7p5t_27/temp9565703453065543452/900f55ed8bef025f39edcc8b8be5e04a2c55c15a.tar.gz: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
ERROR: Analysis of target '//xls/modules/rle:rle_enc_synth_asap7' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 523.907s, Critical Path: 0.33s
INFO: 15 processes: 7 internal, 8 linux-sandbox.
ERROR: Build did NOT complete successfully
//xls/build_rules/tests:generated_frozen_x_sha256sum_test                PASSED in 0.0s
//xls/build_rules/tests:generated_x_sha256sum_test                       PASSED in 0.0s

Executed 2 out of 2 tests: 2 tests pass.
There were tests whose specified size is too big. Use the --test_verbose_timeout_warnings command line option to see which ones these are.
All tests passed but there were other errors during the build.

FAILED:
    Fetching repository @@org_theopenroadproject; Cloning f6da0454e350e93c62264f7b7c95029e1ad2b9fd of https://github.com/The-OpenROAD-Project/OpenROAD.git (shallow fetch failed, fetching full history) 487s
    Fetching repository @@org_theopenroadproject_asap7sc7p5t_28; starting 487s
    Fetching https://github.com/The-OpenROAD-Project/asap7sc7p5t_28/archive/d88477438935a5a388bd6294f682dc405c93c5d2.tar.gz; 393.5 MiB (412,657,061B) 486s
    Fetching repository @@llvm_toolchain_llvm; starting 486s
    Fetching https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/download/llvmorg-17.0.6/clang%2Bllvm-17.0.6-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-22.04.tar.xz; 222.6 MiB (23.4%) 484s

Obviously the issue seems to lie within fetching the openroadproject repository: https://github.com/The-OpenROAD-Project/OpenROAD.
However, I'm totally lost as to what the exact problem could be.
What I've tried so far:

Different bazel versions
Different Ubuntu versions
Increasing git buffer size, since I thought that the repo might be too big to fetch together with everything else
Force git to use http instead of ssh, since I've had some issues cloning repos using ssh in the past

Has anyone had a similar issue when building a project using bazel?
Any help would be greatly appreciated
